# PHP session array variable issue

Tags: php, arrays, session, post, forms

I have a html form which I use to ask a set of multiple choice questions. After a visitor answers a question, he/she will be redirected back to the same page again. And his/her response from last questions will be used via $_POST to query another unique question from MYSQL database, and so on for many questions. So I want to use the PHP session to store all the questions which have already been queried using a PHP array session variable. I tried to array_push all the question ids which have been queried already. However, each time I array_push the most current question id, the previous question id is lost in the session variable. How do I fix this so that the session array will keep all the queried question ids? Thanks!

```
//file name is test.php  
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['used_id'] = array ();
array_push($_SESSION['used_id'],$_POST('name')) 
?>

<html>
   <form action ="test.php" method = "post">
       <input type = "radio" name = "name" value = "1"> choiceA </input>
       <input type = "radio" name = "name" value = "2"> choiceB </input>
       <input type = "submit">
</html>
```

Comment: `$_POST('name')` You should be seeing an error `Function name must be a string ` If not, did you make a typo in your question? Copy and paste is recommended.

Comment: don't assign blank array to the session user_id.directly use the user name.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems n your code:

`$_SESSION['used_id'] = array ();` resets your used_id array every time you call your script.
Test first if there is already an array! `if(is_array($_SESSION['used_id']))`

and then access your $_POST array with square brackets: `$_POST['name']`!

Answer (score 0):

You're emptying the array each time. Set it only the first time, check by using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
// if not set, create the array
if (!isset($_SESSION['used_id'])) $_SESSION['used_id'] = array();
```

Also this line is problematic, you should be using square brackets and end with a semi-colon.

```
// array_push($_SESSION['used_id'],$_POST('name')) 
array_push($_SESSION['used_id'], $_POST['name']);
```